R take action on dataframe columns based on vector by names
Let's say I have a simple dataframe and vector as shown below. I want to divide the columns in df by their corresponding values in x. So column a in df would be divided by 2, column b would be divided by 4, and column c would remain undivided. I can write a loop to do this, but is there a simpler way?
# set up df and x
df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=6:10, c=11:15)
x <- c(2,4,3)
names(x) <- c('a','b','d')

# Loop to do what I want
for (v in names(df)){
  if (v %in% names(x)){
    df[v] <- df[v]/x[v]
  }
}


You should use [[ for data.frames. df[[v]] <- df[[v]]/x[v]

Although probably not the fastest solution, sweep() is made for this. Just find a way to index correctly.
# idx = !is.na(match(colnames(df), names(x))) 
# see thelatemail's comment below:
idx = intersect(colnames(df), names(x)) 
df[idx] = sweep(df[idx], 2, x[idx], "/")
df
    a    b  c
1 0.5 1.50 11
2 1.0 1.75 12
3 1.5 2.00 13
4 2.0 2.25 14
5 2.5 2.50 15


I reckon this is pretty good - maybe idx <- intersect(names(df), names(x)) for another way to do the indexing. There shouldn't be any order issues as you're overwriting df without changing the column order.

I hope this works well for you
list2DF(
    Map(
        \(x, y) x / y^(!is.na(y)),
        df,
        x[names(df)]
    )
)

which gives
    a    b  c
1 0.5 1.50 11
2 1.0 1.75 12
3 1.5 2.00 13
4 2.0 2.25 14
5 2.5 2.50 15



is there a simpler way?

I would say a loop is usually the simplest way. But I would avoid checking v %in% names(x) on every iteration:
cols <- intersect(names(df), names(x))
for (v in cols) df[[v]] <- df[[v]] / x[v]

Could do the same with lapply:
df[cols] <- lapply(cols, \(v) df[[v]] / x[v])

